# arraycontroller nsmutablearray add programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarraycontroller

I trying to add a data on table view via Array Controller thats bind to a NSMutableArray.
On the IB property it looks like this :

[image: IB Property]
[image: File's owner]

and on the code I tried to add the NSMutableArray dynamically then reload the view, bu nothings happened.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        NSMutableDictionary *group = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [group setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d", @"Group", i] forKey:@"groupname"];
        [contentArray addObject:group];
    }
    [tableContent reloadData];
```

I have been google it and browse the same question in stackoverflow, not found a useful one.

any idea ?

Thanks

**updated**

I wrote above code in File's owner class.

Comment: What class is the code you posted in? And, did you log contentArray to make sure it has the objects in it that you expect?

Comment: @rdelmar contentArray is refer to NSMutableArray, and tableContent is refer to NSTableView which an IBOutlet.

Comment: That's not the question I asked.  What class is the code that you posted in?  Is it in the app delegate?

Comment: not an app delegate, but the class on file's owner, okay I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the array needs to send a KVO notification to the array controller  (or maybe it's the table view, I'm not sure). The way to do that is:

self.contentArray = contentArray; (or _contentArray if that's what your ivar is called). I'm assuming that contentArray is a property, if not, you should make it one.

Comment: thanks for your answer. hmm... actually I already put my contentArray as a property.

Comment: @arufian yes, but did you add the line I put in my answer?

Comment: yes I put that one, nothings happened. btw, can I ask one simple question(it's not related though). Is it possible to build nstableview with view based for Snow Leopard ?

Comment: I don't remember whether you can do that on Snow Leopard.  Are you using a view based table?  If so what are the columns bound to?  It should be working, there must still be something wrong with the bindings.

Comment: yes I using view based table, I only have one column that contain Text Table Cell View (thats created on IB), then I bound the textfield to a key of contentArray.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The table view's content binding should be bound to the array controller arrangedObjects.  The textField should be bound to Table Cell View with a model key path of objectValue.groupName This is all described in the Table View Programming Guide in the "Creating the Bindings for a View-Based Table View" section

Comment: I see. But unfortunately, I have to implementing cell-based table view instead of view-based table view, because of the requirement. I'll accept this as the right answer.